# How to support arabic language in android?

Tags: android, arabic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to support Arabic text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android)

how to use arabic text and how to get arabic language support in android.unicode.

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewByid(R.id.text);
```

Comment: Follow this helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813) and enjoy! There is a complete description of problem and an algorithm as its solution.

Answer (score 0):

use typeface for the textview and use your arabic ttf for the same.
**tv.setTypeFace** is the API

Comment: Like i have some arabic text.so i need to paste that in my code .but its not supporting arabic.how  to fix that?

Comment: what is your requirement. you want to show arabic text on textview or code?

Comment: String[] listItems = {"exploring", "android", 
             "list", "activities", "دينيش"};

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a firmware feature , I use the latest CyanogenMod 7.1 on my Nexus S and I have the arabic language for the menu and text input .

After that you can use typeface .

Comment: Like i have some arabic text.so i need to paste that in my code .but its not supporting arabic.how  to fix that?